# What and where is /sbin/service in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, filesystem

I am trying to install YouTrack on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop by following the instructions given [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Install-YouTrack-JAR-as-Service-Linux.html). After some steps, the 9th instruction asks to test the installation by running the following command

```
/sbin/service youtrack start
```

When I run the command, I get

```
bash: /sbin/service: No such file or directory
```

I also have tried using `sudo`:

```
$ sudo /sbin/service youtrack start
sudo: /sbin/service: command not found
```

And I have tried to find `service` in the `/sbin/` directory by running the following command. But I get nothing.

```
$sudo ls -lah /sbin/ | grep 'service'
```

So why I can find this file/program? Is there any way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 16.04, the `service` executable is located in `/usr/sbin/`.

So you could either run

```
/usr/sbin/service youtrack start
```

or even just

```
service youtrack start
```

because normally you don't need to specify the full path of the commands you run, as they are usually located in a directory that is part of your PATH environment variable. The shell automatically searches all those directories whenever you try to run a command without full path.

By the way, if you know the command (e.g. `service`) and want to know which executable this will call and where that one is located, you can use the `which` command:

```
$ which service
/usr/sbin/service
```

Comment: Then there must be a mistake in the installation tutorial. They gave the wrong path of the executable (/sbin/service youtrack start). It should be inside the /usr/ directory. Am I right?

Comment: But It should not be a typo. In another old version of the tutorial, they told to execute the same command. I don't understand that if `service` is meant to be in `/usr/sbin/`, why they persistently mention the wrong path.

Older virsion of the tutorial: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/YouTrack+JAR+as+a+Service+on+Linux

Comment: Maybe it was `/sbin/service` in older Ubuntu releases? I don't know, I don't have an older installation here to look it up. Fact is, the `service` executable is in `/usr/sbin` for 16.04 and it is definitely the one that the tutorial wants you to run. Maybe you should try contacting the author or maintainer and report their mistake? Anyway, if this answer solved your problem, please also consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left to mark your question as solved.